# Substitute text with sed and keep part of the original text

Tags: sed, regular-expression, xml

I am trying to convert

```
<id>1</id>
<Name>ENTERPRISE RESOURCE PLANNING</Name>
```

to:

```
<column name="id">1</column>
<column name="Name">ENTERPRISE RESOURCE PLANNING</column>
```

I am assuming the best tool for the job would be `sed`, however I can't figure out how to keep parts of the original text in the replace part.

If I do:

```
$ sed -i 's/<.*>.*<.*>/<column name="\\1">\\2<\/column>/g' filename.xml
```

The output is:

```
<column name="\1">\2</column>
<column name="\1">\2</column>
```

Or doing similar from within `vi`, it outputs:

```
<column name=""></column>
<column name=""></column>
```

How can I make it so that `\1` and `\2` are substituted back to their original values?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use groups, e.g.:

```
$ sed -i 's/<\(.*\)>\(.*\)<.*>/<column name="\1">\2<\/column>/g' filename.xml
```

Probably the most confusing part about REs is that there are various syntactic flavors.

For example sed and vim use *basic regular expressions* where you have to quote `()` to get their meta-meaning.

With *extended regular expressions* (e.g. awk, egrep and less) you have to quote `()` to get the literal meaning. There are similar differences for other meta-characters.

The rationale behind BRE `()` semantics is that when most of your input is C-Code then it is more practical to have to quote parentheses for meta-use.

Comment: This was actually the first thing I tried, but I didn't escape the `(` and `)` characters. Stupid question, but why is that necessary?

Comment: @Mike, good question - updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xmlstarlet`:

1. Add an `name` attribute to all `id` and `Name` nodes, with the value `id` or `Name` as appropriate.
2. Rename all `name` and `id` nodes to `column`.

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed \
    -s '//id'   -t attr -n name -v id \
    -s '//Name' -t attr -n name -v Name \
    -r '//id'   -v column \
    -r '//Name' -v column  file.xml
```

Given an example document like

```xml
<root>
<id>1</id><Name>ENTERPRISE RESOURCE PLANNING</Name>
<id>2</id><Name>ENTERPRISE RESOURCE PLANNING (the return)</Name>
</root>
```

(note that white-spaces between nodes are not important) this would result in

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <column name="id">1</column>
  <column name="Name">ENTERPRISE RESOURCE PLANNING</column>
  <column name="id">2</column>
  <column name="Name">ENTERPRISE RESOURCE PLANNING (the return)</column>
</root>
```